# How can I inspect the routes being used by an Angular resource object?

Tags: angularjs, rest, angular-resource, angular-services

I am trying to use list all the resource in a REST API endpoint using an angular resource object.

When I do a query wit the resource defined in this way I get an empty array:

```
MyApp.factory "Foo", [
  "$resource"
  ($resource) ->
    return $resource("/foo/:format", {},
      query: 
        isArray: true
        params:
          format: 'json'
    )
]
```

but when I specify the query url directly I get the list of resources I expected.

```
MyApp.factory "Foo", [
  "$resource"
  ($resource) ->
    return $resource("/foo/:format", {},
      query:
        url: /foo/?format=json
        isArray: true
        params:
    )
]
```

How does angular construct the urls for resources?

Is there any way to debug and print the query url generated by the resource object into the console?

Answer (score 0):

Action params are a, "Optional set of **pre-bound** parameters for this action."

When you specify a parametrized URL, you set those parameters when you call `Foo.query`

```
MyApp.factory "Foo", [
    "$resource"
    ($resource) ->
    return $resource("/foo/:format", {},
        query: 
            isArray: true
    )
]
```

And then execute the query like `Foo.query( { format: 'json' } );`

You could set a default `format` like:

```
MyApp.factory "Foo", [
    "$resource"
    ($resource) ->
    return $resource("/foo/:format", {},
        query: 
            isArray: true
            paramDefaults:
                format: 'json'
    )
]
```

Comment: Neither passing the format as a parameter to query or or using paramDefaults. Is there any way to spit out the generated url?

Comment: No way that I know of to do that in Angular. Could you use browser developer tools network tab?

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution to my problem, it was produced by django appending trailing slashes.There is a good explanation [here](http://www.masnun.com/2013/09/18/django-rest-framework-angularjs-resource-trailing-slash-problem.html).